# How to pass ID to function after event listener click

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im pretty new to HTML5/Javascript/CSS3 and im confused on exactly how to pass the id of my event listener to the new function. I'm building a video player and this is the volume up and down part, and I would rather be able to use one function for both volume up and volume down using if statements, which would check the id.

Here is what im working with:

```
 volume_up = document.getElementById('volume_up'); //get the volume_up button
 volume_up.addEventListener('click', volumeUp, false); //call function "volumeUp" on click
```

Here is the "volumeUp" function:

```
function volumeUp(click_button){
alert(click_button.id); // i want to be able to get the id here
myMovie.volume = myMovie.volume - 0.1;
}
```

If i was able to get the ID, i could do vol up and vol down in this one function instead of 2 via if statements.

I have tried doing this:

```
   volume_up.addEventListener('click', volumeUp(volume_up), false);
```

and

```
    volume_up.addEventListener('click', volumeUp(volume_up.id), false);
```

with no luck. I have the volume up button linked up, and whenever i press it, the volume does change, and the alert does popup, but it says undefined.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the event handler "this" is bound to the element that fired the event, so you can just use "this.id".

Check out this example: http://jsfiddle.net/vyGdJ/

Comment: When i do it comes back as undefined..hmmm

Comment: the alert box says undefined*

Comment: Alright, i looked at the example, i actually got it working. I was confused with the this part as i thought that was what was to be passed into the function, i didnt know that it was built into Javascript. I got it working now guys. Thanks :D

Comment: What is passed to the function is provided by the javascript engine itself (by most at least). It's an event object that contain information about the event that has occurred. I'd recommend to use a library like jQuery to iron out differences between browsers.

Answer (score 3):

```
document.getElementById('volume_up').addEventListener('click', _volume, false);
document.getElementById('volume_down').addEventListener('click', _volume, false);

function _volume(event){
    if(this.id == 'volume_up') {
        myMovie.volume += 0.1;
    } else {
        myMovie.volume -= 0.1;
    }
}
```

This is just an example. You'll want to use some defensive logic to check for IE and use `attachEvent` instead when applicable.

The reason these didn't work...

```
volume_up.addEventListener('click', volumeUp(volume_up), false);
volume_up.addEventListener('click', volumeUp(volume_up.id), false);
```

...is because you're invoking the function and passing the *result* of `volumeUp` as the callback, which would not be a `typeof == 'function'`